# Prove that maximally entangled states $|\Phi\rangle$ satisfy the identity $(U\otimes I)|\Phi\rangle=(I\otimes U^T)|\Phi\rangle$

Tags: entanglement, unitarity

The definition of maximally entangled state is
\begin{equation}
\vert \Phi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \sum_i \vert i \rangle \vert i \rangle,
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $d$ is the dimension of the hilbert space. Then we have the following identity
\begin{equation}
(U\otimes I)\vert \Phi \rangle= (I\otimes U^T)\vert \Phi \rangle,
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $U$ denotes the unitary matrix.

Equation (2) is from the lower right corner at Page. 7 in [Cross-Platform Verification in Quantum Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.07789.pdf).

My question is how to proof equation (2).

Comment: This is also true for non-unitary operations, which don't need maximally entangled states but only states with maximal Schmidt number https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07731

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by writing
$$
U=\sum_{ij}U_{ji}|j\rangle\langle i|.
$$
Now evaluate
$$
U\otimes I|\Phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_{ij}U_{ji}|j\rangle|i\rangle.
$$
Next, realise that (again,if you don't see it,just write it out long-hand)
$$
\sum_iU_{ji}|i\rangle=U^T|j\rangle,
$$
so this just becomes
$$
U\otimes I|\Phi\rangle=I\otimes U^T|\Phi\rangle.
$$